# Is it possible to use Wicket Fragments within an Extend component?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

I'm trying to use Fragments within an Extend component but it throws an MarkupNotFoundException.

The code is similar to this:

**BasePanel.html**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<wicket:panel xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">

    <div wicket:id="dialog">
        <div class="titlebar">
            <h3 wicket:id="dialogTitle">[[ dialog title ]]</h3>
            <div wicket:id="dialogCloseBtn" class="closeBtn right"></div>
        </div>
        <wicket:child />
    </div>

</wicket:panel>
```

**ChildPanel.html**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<wicket:extend xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">

    <wicket:panel wicket:id="panel1" />

    <wicket:fragment wicket:id="fragment1">
    </wicket:fragment>

</wicket:extend>
```

**ChildPanel.java**

```
public class ChildPanel extends Panel  
{
    public ChildPanel(String id, IModel<?> model) 
    {
         super(id, model);
         add(new Fragment("panel1", "fragment1", this); 
    }
}
```

The problem resides in Wicket *Markup.java* class:

```
public final IMarkupFragment find(final String id)
{
    Args.notEmpty(id, "id");

    MarkupStream stream = new MarkupStream(this);
    stream.setCurrentIndex(0);
    while (stream.hasMore())
    {
        MarkupElement elem = stream.get();
        if (elem instanceof ComponentTag)
        {
            ComponentTag tag = stream.getTag();
            if (tag.isOpen() || tag.isOpenClose())
            {
                if (tag.getId().equals(id))
                {
                    return stream.getMarkupFragment();
                }
                if (tag.isOpen() && !tag.hasNoCloseTag() && !(tag instanceof WicketTag) &&
                    !"head".equals(tag.getName()) && !tag.isAutoComponentTag())
                {
                    stream.skipToMatchingCloseTag(tag);
                }
            }
        }

        stream.next();
    }

    return null;
}
```

When the application iterates over the stream it looks in the **BasePanel markup**. After looking open tag `<div wicket:id="dialog">` it iterates to the closing tag `</div>`, so it didn't look inside the **ChildPanel markup**.

Do you have any suggestion or solution?

Thanks,
Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an opened jira issue related with this topic. You could follow instructions to solve it here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4545.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a `<wicket:fragment>` inside `<wicket:extend>`, but not a `<wicket:panel>` (panel1). Try using `<wicket:container>` instead.

Comment: Hi, I have switch `<wicket:panel>` to `<wicket:contentainer>` but it still throws the MarkupNotFoundException.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not the fragment, but the `<wicket:child/>` tag inside another `wicket:id`-marked tag? Try replacing `add(new Fragment("panel1", "fragment1", this);` with `((MarkupContainer)get("dialog")).add(new Fragment("panel1", "fragment1", this); `

Comment: Thanks Tetsuo, but there is an opened jira issue related with this topic: [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4545](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4545). And the temporal solution is to use the `TransparentWebMarkupContainer` as MarkupProvider. I will close this question.